# Is API Key Required for Direction Apis Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I am using below code to get directions to a particular lat & lng using google api. But I have not used the api key. This app which I am making will soon be pushed to playstore. I just want to make sure what I am doing here is correct or will it cause any problem for me ?

Thanks in advance :)

```
if (pc.getLatitude() != null && pc.getLongitude() != null) {

      double latitude = Double.parseDouble(pc.getLatitude());
      double longitude = Double.parseDouble(pc.getLongitude());

      String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%f,%f (%s)", latitude, longitude, "Location");
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
      if (intent.resolveActivity(mContext.getPackageManager()) != null) {
           Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.toast_opening_google_maps, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           mContext.startActivity(intent);
      } else {
             Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.toast_no_google_maps_warning, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
} else {
     Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.toast_no_ll_warning, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

This is one more example of my api usage

```
 String distanceUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?" +
                "origins=" + mOriginLatLng.latitude + "," + mOriginLatLng.longitude +
                "&destinations=" + destination.latitude + "," + destination.longitude +
                "&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false";
```

Comment: *Is API Key Required for Maps Google API* yes

Comment: without api key your map never be rendered on display..

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry about earlier I was not referring to map but the apis used to get directions to show on the map

Comment: I guess you are opening google map with an Implicit Intent so I think you don't need any api key because your app is calling another app, chrome or google maps app, and those apps are in charge of showing your map.

Comment: @MiguelBenitez what about my second api call ? is it valid to use without api key ?

Comment: I don't know how you are trying to run it.

Comment: @MiguelBenitez what do u mean ? is the question not clear ?

Comment: I am making a http call on distanceUrl and I am parsing the response to get latitude and longitude and storing it in db for later use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents), you don't need an API key to launch Google Maps using an Intent.

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/), you will need an API key to use the     Distance Matrix API.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link. One more question is API Key required even if we are calling from client side (Android device)? As per my knowledge it is only required if we are using it from server side ? Is this correct ?

Comment: And also if api key is required why is my present api is working ? Any idea ?

Comment: Yes, the API key is required. Your example is working for testing purposes. Here https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/ you can find the pricing and plans for several web services (including Distance Matrix API)

Comment: Thanks again. One more question - It says 2500 requests per day. Is it per device or API_KEY ?

Comment: For example I have a project in my developer console in which I have already assigned an app say - com.example.test1 &sha1 finger print. and I now add this project com.example.test2 to the list and use the same api key. Will the request be distributed or each device using these apps will have a seperate request quota ?

Comment: Is per API key, and according to https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/ "Google Maps Distance Matrix API usage is measured in number of elements per day"

Comment: what does elements here refer to any idea ?

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#DirectionsResponseElements "The same daily usage limits apply regardless of how you use the service. The elements per day are calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries."